# How do I count the subsets of a set whose number of elements is divisible by 3? 4?

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $S$ be a set of size $n$.  There is an easy way to count the number of subsets with an even number of elements.  Algebraically, it comes from the fact that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} = (1 + 1)^n$

while

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k {n \choose k} = (1 - 1)^n$.

It follows that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} {n \choose 2k} = 2^{n-1}$.

A direct combinatorial proof is as follows: fix an element $s \in S$.  If a given subset has $s$ in it, add it in; otherwise, take it out.  This defines a bijection between the number of subsets with an even number of elements and the number of subsets with an odd number of elements.

The analogous formulas for the subsets with a number of elements divisible by $3$ or $4$ are more complicated, and divide into cases depending on the residue of $n \bmod 6$ and $n \bmod 8$, respectively.  The algebraic derivations of these formulas are as follows (with $\omega$ a primitive third root of unity):  observe that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} \omega^k {n \choose k} = (1 + \omega)^n = (-\omega^2)^n$

while

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n} \omega^{2k} {n \choose k} = (1 + \omega^2)^n = (-\omega)^n$

and that $1 + \omega^k + \omega^{2k} = 0$ if $k$ is not divisible by $3$ and equals $3$ otherwise.  (This is a special case of the discrete Fourier transform.)  It follows that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n/3} {n \choose 3k} = \frac{2^n + (-\omega)^n + (-\omega)^{2n}}{3}.$

$-\omega$ and $-\omega^2$ are sixth roots of unity, so this formula splits into six cases (or maybe three).  Similar observations about fourth roots of unity show that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n/4} {n \choose 4k} = \frac{2^n + (1+i)^n + (1-i)^n}{4}$

where $1+i = \sqrt{2} e^{ \frac{\pi i}{4} }$ is a scalar multiple of an eighth root of unity, so this formula splits into eight cases (or maybe four).

**Question:**  Does anyone know a direct combinatorial proof of these identities?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382/counting-subsets-with-r-mod-5-elements

Comment: Grouping related questions together: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128490/lacunary-sum-of-binomial-coefficients http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163198/counting-descending-sequences-of-positive-integers http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142260/sum-of-every-kth-binomial-coefficient

Comment: Does [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_sieving) have anything to do with it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/875153

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fix two elements s<sub>1</sub>,s<sub>2</sub>∈S and divide subsets of S into two parts (subsets of S containing only s<sub>2</sub>)∪(subsets of S which contains s<sub>1</sub> if they contain s<sub>2</sub>). The second part contains equal number of sets for all reminders mod 3 (because Z/3 acts there adding s<sub>1</sub>, then s<sub>2</sub>, then removing both of them) -- namely, 2<sup>n-2</sup>. And for the first part we have a bijection with subsets *(edit: with 2 mod 3 elements)* of a set with (n-2) elements.

So we get a recurrence relation that gives an answer 2<sup>n-2</sup>+2<sup>n-4</sup>+... -- i.e. (2<sup>n</sup>-1):3 for even and (2<sup>n</sup>-2):3 for odd n.

---

**Errata.** For n=0,1,5 mod 6 one should add "+1" to the answer from the previous paragraph (e.g. for n=6 the correct answer is 1+20+1=22 and not 21).

Let me try to rephrase the solution to make it obvious. For n=2k divide S on k pairs and consider an action of a group Z/3Z on each pair described in a first paragraph. We get an action of (Z/3Z)<sup>k</sup> on subsets of S, and after removal of it's only fixed point (k-element set consisting of second points from each pair) we get a bijection between subsets which have 0, 1 or 2 elements mod 3. So there are (2<sup>n</sup>-1):3 sets with i mod 3 elements excluding the fixed point *and* to count that point one should add "+1" for i=k mod 3.

And for n=2k+1 there are 2 fixed points — including or not (2k+1)-th element of S — with k+1 and k elements respectively.

Comment: Thanks!  That's easier than I thought it would be.  I'll accept this answer, but if you get ideas about the 4 case I'd certainly still be interested in hearing them.

Comment: I'll certainly try to think about "4 case".

And looks like in "3 case" there is more than meets an eye: in the solution we identify subsets of S (|S|=2k) with P^1(Z/3)^k and consider an action of (Z/3)^k on it; and the only fixed point of the action gives "-1" in the formula. Probably I should think more about this situation. Thanks for the question!

Comment: cf. http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/blog.php?u=3590&b=10590&r=19772#r19772 (link via @Qiaochu Yuan's comment to another question)

Comment: ah, thanks.  I have to admit I never checked either of those solutions...

Answer (score 20):

There's a very pretty combinatorial proof of the general identity $$\sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{n}{rk} = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (1+\omega^j)^n,$$
for $\omega$ a primitive $r$th root of unity, in Benjamin, Chen, and Kindred, "[Sums of Evenly Spaced Binomial Coefficients](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/hmc_fac_pub/535/)," *Mathematics Magazine* 83 (5), pp. 370-373, December 2010.

They show that both sides count the number of closed $n$-walks on $C_r$ beginning at vertex 0, where $C_r$ is the directed cycle on $r$ elements with the addition of a loop at each vertex, and a walk is *closed* if it ends where it starts.

*Left-hand side*: In order for an $n$-walk to be closed, it has to take $kr$ forward moves and $n-kr$ stationary moves for some $k$.

*Right-hand side*: The number of closed walks starting at vertex $j$ is the same regardless of the choice of $j$, and so it suffices to prove that the total number of closed $n$-walks on $C_r$ is $\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (1+\omega^j)^n.$  For each $n$-walk with initial vertex $j$, assign each forward step a weight of $\omega^j$ and each stationary step a weight of $1$.  Define the weight of an $n$-walk itself to be the product of the weights of the steps in the walk.  Thus the sum of the weights of all $n$-walks starting at $j$ is $(1+\omega^j)^n$, and  $\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (1+\omega^j)^n$ gives the total weight of all $n$-walks on $C_r$.  The open $n$-walks can then be partitioned into orbits such that the sum of the weights of the walks in each orbit is $0$.  Thus the open $n$-walks contribute a total of $0$ to the sum $\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (1+\omega^j)^n$.  Since a closed $n$-walk has weight $1$, $\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (1+\omega^j)^n$ must therefore give the number of closed $n$-walks on $C_r$.

---

They then make a slight modification of the argument above to give a combinatorial proof of 
$$\sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{n}{a+rk} = \frac{1}{r} \sum_{j=0}^{r-1} \omega^{-ja}(1+\omega^j)^n,$$
where $0 \leq a < r$.

---

Benjamin and Scott, in "[Third and Fourth Binomial Coefficients](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/hmc_fac_pub/124/)" (*Fibonacci Quarterly*, 49 (2), pp. 99-101, May 2011) give different combinatorial arguments for the specific cases you're asking about, $\sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{n}{3k}$ and $\sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{n}{4k}$.  I prefer the more general argument above, though, so I'll just leave this one as a link and not summarize it.

Answer (score 1):

I try to add details with simple calculation:

for example, I show $\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{6}+\cdots=\frac{1}{3}[2^n+2\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})]$

we know $(1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{2}x^2+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}x^n$, so if in this identity we put $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$ where $\alpha=\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})$respectively, then we get $$2^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots$$, $$(1+\alpha)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\alpha+\binom{n}{2}\alpha^2+\binom{n}{3}\alpha^3+\cdots$$,

$$(1+\alpha^2)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\alpha^2+\binom{n}{2}\alpha^4+\binom{n}{3}\alpha^6+\cdots$$

but if $3\nmid n$, then we can easily see that $1+\alpha^k+\alpha^{2k}=3$ hence

$2^n+(1+\alpha)^n+(1+\alpha^2)^n=3\{\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{6}+\cdots\}$ but since $1+\alpha+\alpha^{2}=0$ hence

$1+\alpha=-\alpha^2=\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$ and also $1+\alpha^2=-\alpha=\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})-i\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$ hence $$2^n+(1+\alpha)^n+(1+\alpha^2)^n=2^n+2\cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})$$, so we get the desired result.