# Sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n - 2k}{n - 1} = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

How do I prove the following identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{2n - 2k}{n - 1} = 0$$

I am trying to use inclusion-exclusion, and this will boil down to a sum like inclusion-exclusion, and the $\binom{2n-2k}{n-1}$ term wouldn't matter (it will be equivalent to set sizes). Is this a correct way to go?

Comment: similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94514/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-1k-binomnk-0

Comment: @ulead86: How is that related?

Comment: I tried reading that - didn't seem like the same question in first look.

Comment: sorry, changed the link (wrong copy+paste)

Comment: @ulead86: Unfortunately the new link seems just as unrelated as the other one.

Comment: Notice that the argument of @joriki shows that this identity is true "for any value of $2$". In other words, for any integers $r,m,n\ge 0$ we have that, if $m<n$, then $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{r(n-k)}{m}=0.$$ Moreover, if $m=n$, then $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{r(n-k)}{n}=r^n.$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In how many ways can you select $m\lt n$ squares on a $2\times n$ board such that exactly $n$ columns contain a selected square?

[*Edit:*]

From the lack of upvotes and the inquiring comment of a distinguished user I conclude that I should explain this perhaps overly laconic answer.

The OP wanted to prove the result by inclusion–exclusion. The number of ways to select $m$ squares on a $2\times n$ board such that at most $j$ particular columns contain a selected square is $\binom{2j}m$. By inclusion–exclusion, if there are $a_j$ ways to do something with at most $j$ particular objects, then there are

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nka_{n-k}
$$

ways to do it with exactly $n$ objects (where the binomial coefficient counts the number of ways of selecting $n-k$ particular ones of the $n$ objects). Putting this together yields the number of ways to select $m$ squares on a $2\times n$ board such that exactly $n$ columns contain a selected square:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk\binom{2n-2k}m\;.
$$

Since it's impossible to have exactly $n$ columns contain a selected square if less than $n$ squares are selected, this is $0$ for $m\lt n$, and thus in particular for $m=n-1$.

Comment: I can answer that question easily (the answer is indeed equal to the right hand side of the equation in the original question), but I fail to see what this weird description has to do with the (more interesting) left hand side. Notably there is nothing alternating in your description.

Comment: @Marc: Sorry for being overly brief; I thought this would work as a hint, but apparently it didn't; I've spelled it out.

Answer (score 10):

The function $g:k\mapsto \binom{2n-2k}{n-1}$ is a polynomial function of degree $n-1$. The operation $f\mapsto\bigl(x\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom knf(x+k)\bigr)$ equals $(-1)^n\Delta^n$, where $\Delta$ is the finite difference operator $f\mapsto\bigl(x\mapsto f(x+1)-f(x)\bigr)$, which kills constant functions and lowers the degree of polynomial functions by $1$. Therefore $(-1)^n\Delta^n(g)=0$, which means that
$$
  x\mapsto\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom kng(x+k)
$$
is the zero function. Now apply for $x=0$ to obtain
$$
  0=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom kng(k) = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom kn\binom{2n-2k}{n-1}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

This can  be done very straightforwardly  and we can  retain the given
range of the index $k.$ Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} {2n-2k\choose n-1}.$$

Introduce
$${2n-2k\choose n-1}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2n-2k}}{z^n} \; dz.$$

This gives for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^n} 
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \frac{1}{(1+z)^{2k}}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^n} 
\left(1-\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}\right)^n
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^n} 
(z^2+2z)^n \; dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
(z+2)^n \; dz = 0.$$

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "very straightforwardly", but +1 for a nice proof :-)

Comment: Thanks. This is the so-called Egorychev method although some of it is probably folklore, Observe the mechanics at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299123).

Comment: Pretty amazing! I wonder why I'd never come across this method before.

Comment: This is basically the Cauchy Residue Theorem as used also at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353963/). Quite possibly some consider it to be self-evident and not in need of a name or of publicity.

Comment: Well, it's one thing to know and recognize the residue theorem, quite another to come up with the idea of using it in this interesting way :-)

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to use [snake oil](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). Use $m$ as a new free variable (for $n - 1$), notice that outside the given range the first binomial coefficient is zero, and write the generating function for the sum we want:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{m \ge 0} z^m \sum_k (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \binom{2 n - 2 k}{m}
  &= \sum_k (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \sum_{m \ge 0} \binom{2 n - 2 k}{m} z^m \\
  &= \sum_k (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (1 + z)^{2 n - 2 k} \\
  &= (1 + z)^{2 n} \sum_k (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (1 + z)^{- 2 k} \\
  &= (1 + z)^{2 n} \left(1 - (1 + z)^{-2}\right)^n \\
  &= \left((1 + z)^2 - 1\right)^n \\
  &= z^n (2 + z)^n
\end{align}$

Now we want the coefficient of $z^m$ of this:

$\begin{align}
[z^m] z^n (2 + z)^n
  &= [z^{m - n}] (2 + z)^n \\
  &= \binom{n}{m - n} 2^{n - (m - n)} \\
  &= \binom{n}{m - n} 2^{2 n - m}
\end{align}$

The original problem asks for $m = n - 1$, sure enough, $\binom{n}{-1} = 0$.

**Note:** The $[z^n]$ notation is described by Knuth as a simpler way to handle Egorychev's "method of coefficients", which I believe is what Marko Riedel is doing.