# How to prove that $\sum_{i-is-even}^n \binom{n}{i} = \sum_{i-is-odd}^n \binom{n}{i}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I need to prove that

$\sum_{i-is-even}^n \binom{n}{i} = \sum_{i-is-odd}^n \binom{n}{i}$

`i` starts from 0.

I succeeded proving this for odd n.
But how to prove it for even n's?

Comment: Hint: Look at the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ and consider $x=-1$

Comment: Hint: Expand $\binom ni = \binom{n-1}{i-1} + \binom{n-1}i$.

Comment: Your assertion can be rephrased as: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k} = 0$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94514/215011

Comment: If $n > 0$ !!!.

Answer (score 1):

We show equality by showing the difference of both sums is zero.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{i=0}\atop{i \text{ even}}}^n&\binom{n}{i}-\sum_{{i=0}\atop{i \text{ odd}}}^n\binom{n}{i}\\\
> &=\sum_{{i=0}\atop{i \text{ even}}}^n\binom{n}{i}(-1)^i+\sum_{{i=0}\atop{i \text{ odd}}}^n\binom{n}{i}(-1)^i\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(-1)^i\tag{2}\\
> &=(1-1)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=0
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we multiply the terms with $(-1)^i$, which is $1$ if $i$ is even and $-1$ if $i$ is odd. This is just a preparation to easily merge both sums.
- In (2) we simplify the expression by adding both sums.
- In (3) we apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)*.