# Proving an equality using Inclusion Exclusion Principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

I found the exact same question that I want to ask here : [Proving $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94514/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-1k-binomnk-0)

From my understanding this doesn't use Inclusion Exclusion Principle and if it does in some way, it was answered a little too briefly for me to comprehend it, i am still new to discrete mathematics and have trouble understanding the concepts.

I am trying to prove the following:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} = 0$$

How would I use IEP to prove the following?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inclusion-Exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):
$$
\left|\,\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\,\right|=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1} \sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_k\leq n} \left|A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k}\right|.
$$

So take $A_i=\{1\},\,\forall i=1,\cdots,n$, and the result follows.

---

Hope this helps.