# Proving that a series of binomials is equal to $0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Prove that 
$$\sum_{x=0}^{n}(-1)^x\binom{n}{x}=0.$$

I think this is some sort of binomial theorem expansion but I am not sure how to start the proof. Does this make sense?

$$0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{x=0}^n\binom nx1^{n-x}(-1)^x$$

Comment: Welcome. You can find how to format your posts [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). People don't like to answer questions that are poorly formatted, do it for your own good.

Comment: After it's been properly formatted with MathJax, it appears to be correct.

Comment: What is $n$? If $n=0$ is it not $1$?

Comment: If you search [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bx%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D(-1)%5Ex%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bx%7D%3D0.%24&p=1) or look in the frequent tab of the posts [tagged binomial-coefficients+summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients+summation), it's very likely that you can find a few posts on this site about the same problem. Here is one of them: [Proving $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94514).

Answer (score 1):

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a^kb^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}$$

put $a=-1$ and $b=1$

$$(-1+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k1^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k1^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}=(1-1)^n=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course that’s the proof

$$0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{x=0}^n\binom nx1^{n-x}(-1)^x=\sum_{x=0}^n (-1)^x \binom n x $$

and similarly

$$2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{x=0}^n\binom nx1^{n-x}(1)^x=\sum_{x=0}^n  \binom n x $$