# Given a finite set U, how can we enumerate all subsets of U that have an odd number of elements

Tags: optimization

That is pretty much this, given a finite set U, how can we enumerate all subsets
of U that have an odd number of elements? This is a question about enumaration on my optimization subject and I really don't know where to start

Comment: There is the same number of sets with the odd number of elements and sets with the even number of elements. Browse the answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94514/proving-sum-k-0n-1k-binom-nk-0 to see different ways to prove that.

Comment: I am really in the beggining of learning this, so would you mind to explain in words so I can Undersand the concept?