# Alternating sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

> Calculate the sum:
>
> $$ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n+1\choose k+1} $$

I don't know if I'm so tired or what, but I can't calculate this sum. The result is supposed to be $1$ but I always get something else...

Comment: Hint: Use the binomial theorem to expand $(1-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: $ (x + 1)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k. $

Comment: Oh, @Henning: I typed my answer up, but it turns out I'm 5 minutes after your (earlier posted, yet containing more or less everything in my answer) comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluate $ \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2k}+\cdots$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42797/evaluate-binomn0-binomn2-binomn4-cdots-binomn2k-cdots)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) we have:
$$ (1 + (-1))^{n+1} = {{n+1} \choose 0} (-1)^0 + {{n+1} \choose 1} (-1)^1 + \ldots + {{n+1} \choose {n+1}} (-1)^{n+1}.$$
"Divide" by ${-1}$ to get:
$$ - (1 - 1)^{n+1} = -{{n+1} \choose 0} + \color{blue}{{{n+1} \choose 1} (-1)^0 + \ldots + {{n+1} \choose {n+1}} (-1)^{n}}.$$
This pretty much solves it.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

1. $\displaystyle (1-1)^{n+1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} {n \choose k}1^k(-1)^{n-k}$
2. What terms are or aren't in your sum that are in the one above?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see it: prove that
$$\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\,\,\,,\,\,\text{so}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\cdot 1^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\cdot 1^{n-k}\binom{n}{k+1}=$$
$$=(1+(-1))^n-\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k+1}\cdot 1^{n-k-1}\binom{n}{k+1}=0-(1-1)^n+1=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n+1\choose k+1}=-\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+1} {n+1\choose k+1}= $$
$$=-\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+1} {n+1\choose k+1}\right)=$$
$$=-\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{j} {n+1\choose j}+(-1)^{0} {n+1\choose 0}-(-1)^{0} {n+1\choose 0}\right)= $$
$$=-\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n+1} (-1)^{j} {n+1\choose j}-(-1)^{0} {n+1\choose 0}\right)=-(1-1)^{n+1}+1=1$$