# How to calculate the binomial sum $S=\mathop{\sum}\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{4}\rfloor}\binom{n}{4i}$?

Tags: combinatorics

How to calculate the sum $S=\mathop{\sum}\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{4}\rfloor}\binom{n}{4i}$ ? Or how to get a good upper bound on $S$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: You might guess that this will be about a quarter of the full binomial sum so $2^{n-2}$

Comment: @Henry: You might guess, but will it be true?...

Comment: The closed fomula is $\frac14\left(2^n+(1+i)^n+(1-i)^n+0^n\right)$ here we take $0^0=1.$

Comment: Calculate it for the first few values of $n$, then look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: This can be rewritten as $$2^{n-2}+2^{(n-2)/2}\cos(n\pi/4)$$ for $n>0.$

Answer (score 0):

As we are interested in every fourth term

let us consider $x^4=1,x=\pm i,\pm1$

Let $$a(1+1)^n+b(1-1)^n+c(1-i)^n+d(1+i)^n=S=?$$

Compare the coefficients of $\binom nr$ where $r=4i,4i+1,4i+2,4i+3$ to find

$$a+b+c+d=1$$

$$a-b-ci+di=0$$

$$a+b-c-d=0$$

$$a-b+ci-di=0$$

Add second and fourth $$a-b=0$$

Then subtract second from the fourth

$$i(c-d)$$

From the first  $$2b+2d=1$$

From the third $$2b-2d=0$$

$$\implies b=d=\dfrac14$$