# Find the sum of $\binom n0 - \binom n2 +\binom n4 -\binom n6 \cdots$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the sum of $\binom n0 - \binom n2 +\binom n4 -\binom n6 \cdots$

---

Using Binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$, 
$$ \binom n0 +\binom n1 x^1 + \binom n 2 x^2 + \cdots + \binom n nx^n $$
Substituting $x = i$,
$$(1+i)^n = \binom n0 +\binom n1 i^1 + \binom n 2 i^2 + \cdots + \binom n ni^n $$
$$(1+i)^n = \binom n0 +\binom n1 i - \binom n 2  - \binom n 3 i\cdots + \binom n ni^n $$
How to proceed further?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384818/how-to-calculate-the-binomial-sum-s-mathop-sum-limits-i-0-lfloor-fracn/3384901#3384901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have $$(1+i)^{n}= \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} i + \binom{n}{2}i^2 + \cdots = \binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{4} + i \cdot\left[\binom{n}{1}-\binom{n}{3} + \cdots\right]$$

- Write $(1+i)^{n}= (\sqrt{2})^{n}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{n}$ and see if you can find the real part of this term.

Comment: How did you get the polar form of $(1+i)^n$ ?

Comment: Note that $1+i  = \sqrt{2}e^{i \pi/4}$. Hence the polar form of $(1+i)^n$ is $\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n e ^{i n\pi/4}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try taking the real part of $(1+i)^n$ in two different ways.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\frac12\left(i^k+(-i)^k\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
1&\text{if }k\equiv0&\pmod4\\
0&\text{if }k\equiv1&\pmod4\\
-1&\text{if }k\equiv2&\pmod4\\
0&\text{if }k\equiv3&\pmod4
\end{array}\right.
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac12\left(i^k+(-i)^k\right)
&=\frac12\left((1+i)^n+(1-i)^n\right)\\
&=2^{n/2}\frac{e^{in\pi/4}+e^{-in\pi/4}}2\\[9pt]
&=2^{n/2}\cos(n\pi/4)
\end{align}
$$