# Binomial coefficient --sums

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I need help solving this task, if anyone have similar problem, it would help me.

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{673}   
 \binom{2019}{3i}$

More precisely I don't know how to start at all, any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213583/show-that-sum-k-0n-binom3n3k-frac8n2-1n3

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384818/how-to-calculate-the-binomial-sum-s-mathop-sum-limits-i-0-lfloor-fracn