# Sum of combinatorics sequence $\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{3} +\cdots+ \binom{n}{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I need to find sum like  $$\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{3} +\cdots+ \binom{n}{n-1},\qquad \text{ for even } n$$

**Example:**

Find the sum of $$\binom{20}{1} + \binom{20}{3} +\cdots+ \binom{20}{19}=\ ?$$

Comment: interestingly enough for $n$ odd by symmetry you get this to be exactly half of the entire row, i.e. $2^{n-1}$

Comment: Very similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42797/evaluate-binomn0-binomn2-binomn4-cdots-binomn2k-cdots If you search a bit, you can probably find several other question on the same topic.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:**
Consider the difference between:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{20}{k}1^k = (1+1)^{20}\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{k=0}^{20}\binom{20}{k}(-1)^k = (1-1)^{20}.$$

Answer (score 4):

The important [binomial theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html) states that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} x^ky^{n-k}=(x+y)^n
\end{equation}

Setting $x=1$ and $y=1$, we have the following relation

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} =2^n
\end{equation}

and setting $x=-1$ and $y=1$, we have the following relation

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} (-1)^k=0
\end{equation}

Hence we have

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2k-1} =\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\right)=2^{n-1}.
\end{equation}

This may be easier to see with your example

\begin{align}
&\binom{20}{1}+\binom{20}{3}+\cdots+\binom{20}{19}=\\
&\frac{1}{2}\left[\color{red}{\binom{20}{0}}+\binom{20}{1}+\color{red}{\binom{20}{2}}+\cdots+\binom{20}{20}-\left(\color{red}{\binom{20}{0}}-\binom{20}{1}+\color{red}{\binom{20}{2}}+\cdots+\binom{20}{20}\right)\right]
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

If you know your Pascal's triangle, you know that 
$$\binom{20}{1} + \binom{20}{3} +..+ \binom{20}{19}= \sum_{k=0}^{19} \binom{19}{k}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{k = 0}^{9}{20 \choose 2k + 1}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{20}{20 \choose k}\half\bracks{1 - \pars{-1}^{k}} =
\half\braces{\pars{1 + 1}^{20} - \bracks{1 + \pars{-1}}^{20}}
\\[3mm] & = \color{#f00}{2^{19}} = 524288
\end{align}