# Prove ${2n\choose0} + {2n\choose2} + \dots + {2n\choose{2n}} = 2^{2n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Prove the identity:
>   $$
> {2n\choose0} + {2n\choose2} + \dots + {2n\choose{2n}} = 2^{2n-1}
> $$
>
> $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Progress:

I've tried using the binomial theorem to get:
$$
2^{2n-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1} {{2n-1}\choose k}
$$
Followed by Pascal's:
$$
{2n\choose k}={{2n-1}\choose k}+{{2n-1}\choose{k-1}}
$$ Then:
$$
2^{2n-1}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1} \Bigg({2n\choose k}-{{2n-1}\choose{k-1}}\Bigg)
$$ However, I don't feel right about this.

Comment: $$\binom{2n}{2k}=\binom{2n-1}{2k-1}+\binom{2n-1}{2k}.$$

Comment: See also: [Evaluate $ \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2k}+\cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42797) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/42797).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $2^{2n} = (1+1)^{2n} = {2n\choose0} + {2n\choose1} + {2n\choose2} \dots + {2n\choose{2n}}$.

$0 = (1+(-1))^{2n} = {2n\choose0} - {2n\choose1} + {2n\choose2} \dots - {2n\choose{2n-1}} + {2n\choose{2n}}$. Now add these two equations and we get

$2^{2n} = 2({2n\choose0} + {2n\choose2} + \dots + {2n\choose{2n}})$. Therefore, ${2n\choose0} + {2n\choose2} + \dots + {2n\choose{2n}} = 2^{2n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The left side is the number of subsets in $\{1,2,...,2n\}$ with even power and the number of them is half of all subsets that is right side.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a combinatorial proof. Let $E$ be the set of subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ containing an even number of elements. Then

- $E$ can be partitioned as $E_0 \cup E_2 \cup \cdots \cup E_{2n}$, where $E_{k}$ is the set of subsets of size $k$.
  $$|E| = \binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{2} + \cdots + \binom{2n}{2n}$$
- $E$ is in bijection with the set $O$ of subsets of odd size (proving this is a good exercise: the idea behind defining the bijection $E \to O$ is to remove $2n$ from a subset if it is an element and to add $2n$ if it is not). But then we have $|E|=|O|$, and so
  $$2^{2n} = |\mathcal{P}(\{1,2,\dots,2n\})| = |E \cup O| = |E|+|O| = 2|E|$$
  so that $|E|=2^{2n-1}$

Putting this together yields
$$\binom{2n}{0} + \binom{2n}{2} + \cdots + \binom{2n}{2n} = 2^{2n-1}$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

You know that
$$
(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}x^i.
$$
Fix $x=1$ and $x=-1$ and you get
$$
2^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le n}\\i\text{ even } }\binom{n}{i}=\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le n}\\i\text{ odd } } \binom{n}{i}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le n}\\i\text{ even } }\binom{n}{i}=\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le n}\\i\text{ odd } } \binom{n}{i}=2^{n-1}.
$$