# Bijective proof for equal number of odd-sized/even-sized subsets of a finite set

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of even and odd subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15591/number-of-even-and-odd-subsets)

Let $X$ be a finite set of cardinality $n$. Let ${\cal E}$ ($\cal O$ )denote the set of all subsets of $X$ with an even (odd) number of elements. It is easy to see that $\cal E$ and $\cal O$ contain the same number of subsets ; indeed, Newton’s binomial formula gives

$$
0=0^n=(1-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k=
\sum_{k \ \text{even}} \binom{n}{k} -\sum_{k \ \text{odd}} \binom{n}{k}=
|{\cal E}|-|{\cal O}|
$$

When $n$ is odd, there is a simpler, more combinatorial proof  : $Y \mapsto X \setminus Y$ defines a bijection between $\cal E$ and $\cal O$. Is there a similar, combinatorial, bijection between  $\cal E$ and $\cal O$ when $n$ is even ?

Comment: Fix one element $x$.  Given a set $S$, either add $x$ to it or take it out, whichever you can do.  Not posting as an answer because this is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @Carl : please tell me if you find a duplicate, it didn’t appear in the list of "similar questions" when I was writing out the question.

Comment: Here's the first one I found: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15591/number-of-even-and-odd-subsets

Comment: @Carl : right, I’ll check more carefully next time. I would have deleted this question if it didn’t have an upvoted answer already.

Comment: @Carl: I prefer the way this question is asked and Ittay's answer over the original.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First note that the claim only holds if $n>0$. There is a general combinatorial proof that works for $n$ even or odd: since $n>0$ there is at least one element in  $X$, call it $x_0$. Now define $f:E\to O$ by mapping $A\in E$ to $A\cup \{x_0\}$ if $x_0\notin A$ and to $A-\{x_0\}$ if $x_0\in A$. $f$ is easily seen to have an inverse (defined in a completely analogous way to $f$'s definition), and so is a bijection.

Comment: In fact, $f$ is its own inverse.

Comment: note quite since the domain and codomain of $f$ are different you can't even compose $f$ with itself.

Comment: I was thinking of $f$ as a map ${\cal P}(X) \to {\cal P}(X)$

Comment: then sure, it is its own inverse, but that is not the $f$ I used in the proof.

Comment: Yes, in your proof there would be a second map $g: O \to E$ defined by exactly the same formula as $f$.

Comment: yes, that is what the last line says.