# An identity on Stirling number of the first and the second kind.

Tags: stirling-numbers

I have a difficulty in proving the identity

$\sum_{i=k}^n S(n+1,i+1)s(i,k) = \binom{n}{k}$

where 
$s(n,k)$ is the stirling number of the first kind and

$S(n,k)$ is the stirling number of the second kind.

I tried to show this equality by arguing a combinatorial interpretation but I failed. When I check this for $n=4, k=2$, I felt hard to interpret this in combinatorial situation.

And next, my second trial was using the generating function but I failed.

I prefer to have the combinatorial proof. However I need any comment to prove this identity. Please give me any advice. Thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that you mean the *signed* Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: Yes I meant signed stirling number of the first kind. Sorry for making you confused.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we seek to verify that
$$\sum_{q=k}^n {n+1\brace q+1} (-1)^{q+k} 
\left[q\atop k\right] = {n\choose k}$$
where we have  used Stirling numbers of the second  and the first kind.

Introduce the generating function
$$H(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}
\sum_{q=k}^n {n+1\brace q+1} (-1)^{q+k} 
\left[q\atop k\right]$$

We have to show that this is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {n\choose k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n=k}^\infty {n\choose k} \frac{z^n}{n!}
\\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {n+k\choose k} \frac{z^{n+k}}{(n+k)!}
= \frac{z^k}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{z^{n}}{n!}
= \frac{z^k}{k!} \exp(z).$$

We extend  $q$ back to zero  because the Stirling number  of the first
kind is zero in the added range and start re-writing to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}
\sum_{q=0}^n {n+1\brace q+1} (-1)^{q+k} 
\left[q\atop k\right]
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^\infty \left[q\atop k\right]
(-1)^{q+k} \sum_{n\ge q} {n+1\brace q+1} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Recall the combinatorial class for set partitions which is
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U} \times\textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$
which gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

which yields
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {n\brace q} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q!}.$$

Therefore
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {n+1\brace q} \frac{z^n}{n!}
= \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{q-1}}{(q-1)!} \exp(z).$$

This yields for the main generating function
$$H(z) = \exp(z) \sum_{q=0}^\infty \left[q\atop k\right] (-1)^{q+k}
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{q}}{q!}.$$

Recall furthermore the species of cycle decompositions
$$\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U} \times\textsc{CYC}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{W}))$$

which gives the generating function
$$G(w, u) = \exp\left(u\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)\right).$$

so that
$$\sum_{q=0}^\infty (-1)^{q+k} \left[q\atop k\right] \frac{w^q}{q!}
= (-1)^k [u^k] \exp\left(u\left(\log\frac{1}{1+w}\right)\right)
\\ = \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1+w}\right)^k.$$

This yields for $H(z)$ the closed form
$$H(z) = \exp(z)
\frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)}\right)^k
\\ = \exp(z) \frac{(-1)^k }{k!} \left(\log(1/\exp(z))\right)^k
= \exp(z) \frac{(-1)^k  (-1)^k z^k}{k!}
\\ = \exp(z) \frac{z^k}{k!}$$

as claimed.

**Remark.** This all looks very familiar but I can't seem to locate the relevant post at this time.

**Addendum.** In order to be fully  rigorous here we need to prove the
*formal power series* identity
$$\log\frac{1}{1+(\exp(z)-1)} = -z.$$

This is
$$\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q}.$$

We see that there is no constant coefficient (so far so good) because
$$\exp(z)-1 = z + \frac{1}{2}z^2 + \frac{1}{6} z^3 + \cdots$$

Moreover the  only contribution to  the coefficient on  $z$ originates
wth $q=1$ and is equal to minus one. It remains to show that for $m\gt
1$ the coefficient on $z^m$ is zero.

Re-write this as follows:
$$[z^m] \sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q (q-1)! \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q!}.
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q (q-1)! [z^m] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^q}{q!}
\\ =  \sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q (q-1)!
\frac{1}{m} [z^{m-1}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{q-1}}{(q-1)!} \exp(z)$$

which yields for the sum

$$\frac{1}{m} [z^{m-1}] \exp(z)
\sum_{q=1}^m (-1)^q (\exp(z)-1)^{q-1}
\\ = - \frac{1}{m} [z^{m-1}] \exp(z)
\sum_{q=1}^m (-1)^{q-1} (\exp(z)-1)^{q-1}
\\ = - \frac{1}{m} [z^{m-1}] \exp(z)
\frac{1-(1-\exp(z))^m}{1-(1-\exp(z))}
\\ = - \frac{1}{m} [z^{m-1}]
(1-(1-\exp(z))^m).$$

As before $1-\exp(z)$  has no constant term  and hence $(1-\exp(z))^m$
starts at  $(-1)^m z^m.$  Therefore we  get $-1$  when $m=1$  and zero
otherwise, which is the claim.

This concludes the argument.

**Comment.**  It  all depends  which  identities  are to  be  accepted
without proof. We get more work if  we try to derive a result from the
basics.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\sum_{i=k}^n (-1)^{i-k} {n+1\brace i+1} {i\brack k} =
\sum_{i=k}^n (-1)^{i-k} {n+1\brace i+1} \left(\sum_{j=k}^i (-1)^{j-k} {i+1\brack j+1} {j\choose k}\right) = $$ $$ = \sum_{j=k}^n \left(\sum_{i=j}^n (-1)^{i-j}{n+1\brace i+1} {i+1\brack j+1} \right) {j\choose k} =
\sum_{j=k}^n \delta_{n,j} {j\choose k} = {n\choose k} ,$$

with $n\brack k$ and $n\brace k$ being the Stirling number of the first and second kind respectively.