# Showing that $x^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n\brace k}(x)(x-1)\ldots (x-k+1)$ holds for all numbers, not just positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I just finished proving that this statement holds for all positive integers $r$ (through a combinatorial argument) $$r^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n\brace k}(r)(r-1)\ldots (r-k+1)$$ (where the curly braces indicate the Stirling set numbers) However, I'm being asked to show that this holds for all numbers $x$. That is $$x^n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n\brace k}(x)(x-1)\ldots (x-k+1)$$ The hint we received was that we should note that the second equation has at most $n$ solutions. However, I'm not sure how that will help me here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $p_l(x) = x^n$ and $p_r$ be the right hand side above. Both are polynomials of degree $n$ and $p_l(k) = p_r(k)$ for $k=0,...,n$, hence they are equal.

Comment: Okay, I see that's a good approach too. For me, I think Brian explained it very clearly as well down below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll expand on the hint. Write the second equation in the form

$$f(x)=x^n-\sum_{k=1}^n{n\brace k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-i)\;;$$

$f(x)$ is a polynomial, and you’ve shown that $f(r)=0$ for each $r\in\Bbb Z^+$. What polynomial has infinitely many zeroes?

Comment: Ah, I see the value of proving the first statement now. From the first statement, we know that $$f(x)=x^n-\sum_{k=1}^n{n\brace k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-i)$$ must have infinitely many zeros, and therefore $f(x)$ must be the zero polynomial. From there, we're looking at $$x^n-\sum_{k=1}^n{n\brace k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-i)=0$$ and we can just bring the summation to the other side. Thank you :)

Comment: @user3803721: You’re welcome. This is a cute trick that you’ll probably see again if you study much combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we seek to verify that
$$x^n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} x^{\underline{k}}$$
for all $x$ including $x$ complex.

We start with the basic

$$x^{\underline{k}} = \sum_{q=1}^k 
\left[k\atop q\right] (-1)^{k+q} x^q.$$

This  follows from  the  defining recurrence  of  the signed  Stirling
numbers of the first kind and certainly holds for any $x.$

Substitute this into the target sum to get

$$x^n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} 
\sum_{q=1}^k 
\left[k\atop q\right] (-1)^{k+q} x^q
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^n x^q
\sum_{k=q}^n {n\brace k} \left[k\atop q\right] (-1)^{k+q}.$$

We thus have to show that
$$\sum_{k=q}^n {n\brace k} \left[k\atop q\right] (-1)^{k+q}
= \begin{cases} 1 \quad\text{if}\quad q=n 
\\ 0 \quad\text{if}\quad 1\le q\lt n.\end{cases}.$$

The first of these follows by inspection. For the second
recall the species for set partitions which is
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U} \mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))$$
which gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$$

and the species of cycle decompositions
$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U} \mathfrak{C}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{W}))$$

which gives the generating function
$$H(w, u) = \exp\left(u\left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)\right).$$

Substitute these into the sum to get

$$n! [z^n] \sum_{k=q}^n \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}
k! [w^k] (-1)^{k+q} 
\frac{1}{q!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^q.$$

Now the exponential term makes  a zero contribution to the coefficient
extractor  at  the  front when  $k\gt  n$  so  we  may extend  $k$  to
infinity.  The logarithmic  term  does not  contribute  to the  second
coefficient extractor when $k\lt q$ so  we may start $k$ at zero. This
yields

$$n! (-1)^q [z^n] \sum_{k\ge 0} (\exp(z)-1)^k
(-1)^{k} [w^k]
\frac{1}{q!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-w}\right)^q.$$

Now what we have here in $w$ is an *annihilated coefficient extractor*
(ACE) that simplifies to

$$n! (-1)^q [z^n]
\frac{1}{q!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-(1-\exp(z))}\right)^q
= n! (-1)^q [z^n] \frac{1}{q!} (-z)^q.$$

This is zero unless $q=n$ when it is one as claimed and we are done.

**Remark.** If there are any  issues with the last simplification here
it can be  verified using *formal power series* only  and the proof is
at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467247/).

**Remark, II.**  There are several  more examples of the  technique of
*annihilated    coefficient   extractors*    at    this   [MSE    link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184319/)  and at  this [MSE
link  II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213727/)  and  also
here             at             this             [MSE             link
III](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130883/).