# Prove that Stirling numbers satisfy the identity $\sum_{m} \binom {n}{m}S(m,k)S(n-m,l)= \binom{k + l}{l}S(n,k + l)$

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

$\sum_{m} \binom {n}{m}S(m,k)S(n-m,l)= \binom{k + l}{l}S(n,k + l)$.
How do I give a combinatorial proof of this identity?

My attempt:

LHS: choose m elements out of $n$ total elements then partition $m$ into $k$ and the rest into $l$.

RHS: partition n elements into $k + l$ boxes, then from the boxes choose $l$ elements to be special.

Comment: Did you try writing down the definition of the Stirling numbers into the equation? Maybe take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279874/proof-of-an-equation-involving-stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467247/an-identity-on-stirling-number-of-the-first-and-the-second-kind

Comment: Your attempt seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in an algebraic proof, it can be done as follows.
Goal is

$$\sum_{m=k}^{n-l} {n\choose m} {m\brace k} {n-m\brace l}
= {k+l\choose l} {n\brace k+l}.$$

The LHS is

$$\sum_{m=k}^{n-l} {n\choose m}
m! [z^m] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}
(n-m)! [w^{n-m}] \frac{(\exp(w)-1)^l}{l!}.$$

This is

$$n! [w^n] \frac{(\exp(w)-1)^l}{l!}
\sum_{m=k}^{n-l} w^m [z^m] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Now we may  extend $m$ beyond $n-l$ to infinity  because if $m\gt n-l$
the least  power of $w$ that  appears is $l+m  \gt n$ (this is  due to
$\exp(z)-1 = z + \cdots$) which does not contribute to the coefficient
extractor $[w^n]$ in front. We obtain

$$n! [w^n] \frac{(\exp(w)-1)^l}{l!}
\sum_{m\ge k} w^m [z^m] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Note that $(\exp(z)-1)^k$ starts at $z^k,$ so the remaining sum copies
the term in $z$ to a term in $w$ and we find

$$n! [w^n] \frac{(\exp(w)-1)^l}{l!}
\frac{(\exp(w)-1)^k}{k!}
\\ = n! [w^n] {k+l\choose l} \frac{(\exp(w)-1)^{k+l}}{(k+l)!}
\\ = {k+l\choose l} {n\brace k+l}.$$

This concludes the proof. What we have used here is a so-called
*annihilated coefficient  extractor* (ACE).