# How to prove even subsets equal to odd subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

There is question that I don't know how to prove.
we have set $A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\},\; O=\{B\mid B⊆A,\text{ odd }B\},\; E=\{B\mid B⊆A,\text{ even }B\}$ it ask to prove that subsets even equal to subsets odd by proving that $f:O\to E$ is an injective and surjective function

Comment: See also [Exactly half of the elements of $\mathcal P(A)$ are odd-sized](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248245),
[Number of even and odd subsets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15591),
[Number of subsets of even and odd](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278169)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
f(B) = \begin{cases} B\smallsetminus\{1\} & \text{if }1\in B, \\
B\cup\{1\} & \text{if }1\not\in B. \end{cases}
$$
This works unless $n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, one way to show that two sets have the same size is to construct a bijection between the two sets. So, find a function $f:E\to O$ which you can prove is a bijection. Hint: What happens if you fix some element in $A$ and add it to a given subset in $E$? What happens if you remove it from a given subset in $E$? If you answer these questions carefully you might get an idea of how to construct $f$. Then you can prove it is a bijection.