# Let $a_n$ be the number of even sized subsets of $ \{1,\ldots,n\}$. How do I find the exponential generating funtion $a_n$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

We need to use the Maclaurin series of $\cosh(x)$.

Comment: It is a classic exercise to prove that $a_{n} = 2^{n-1}$ ([for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15591/number-of-even-and-odd-subsets)) - does that help?

Comment: It’s quite easy to derive this exponential generating function without any reference to the hyperbolic cosine. In what sense are you required to use its Maclaurin series?

Comment: I have to use the Product formula, exponential version.  Where I have to assume a_n be the number of ways to build a certain structure on an n-th element set, and b_n be the number of ways to build another structure on an n-th element. And c_n be the number of ways to seperate [n] into the disjoint subsets S and T, such that the union of S and T = [n].

Comment: and then build a structure of the first kind on S, and a structure of the second kind on T. Let A(x), B(x) and C(x) be the respective exponential generating functions of the sequences {a_n}, {b_n}, and c_{n}. Then A(x)B(x) = C(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: The Maclaurin series for $\cosh x$ is

$$\cosh x=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\,,$$

so it corresponds to the sequence $\langle e_n:n\ge 0\rangle$, where

$$e_n=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
0,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd.}
\end{cases}$$

The number of even-sized subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n}{2k}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n}ke_k\cdot 1\,.$$

This last expression is the coefficient of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ in the product of the power series $\sum_{n\ge 0}e_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $\sum_{n\ge 0}1\cdot\frac{x^n}{n!}$ corresponding to the sequences $\langle e_n:n\ge 0\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$. Now all you have to do is identify the generating function for that last sequence and put the pieces together.

You can check your result be deriving it in a different way. The empty set has one even-sized subset, and $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ has $2^{n-1}$ even-sized subsets for $n\ge 1$, so the power series that you want is

$$1+\sum_{n\ge 1}2^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+\frac12\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{(2x)^n}{n!}\,.$$

Write this in terms of an exponential function, and compare that result with the [ways of expressing $\cosh x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Exponential_definitions) in terms of exponential functions.