# Counting descending sequences of positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

The complete question I would like to answer is:

Given positive integers $k,n$, how many **descending** lists of non-negative integers $(x_1~x_2\ldots x_k)$ are there such that $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = n$?

As a quick first insight, it's clear that the general problem will come if we can find the solution for $k=n$. It would take a long time to explain the buildup, but I have reduced the problem to calculating the value $f(n,n)$ of a function recursively defined by:
$$
f(n,m) = f(n,m-1) + f(n-m,\min(m,n-m))~,
$$ $$
f(n,2) = 1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor~~;~f(n,1) = f(n,0) = 1~.
$$
For a less clunky reformulation, posit that $f(a,b) = f(a,\min(a,b))$ for each pair $a,b$, and we have $f(n,m) = f(n,m-1) + f(n-m,m)$.

Now my attempt so far is repeatedly applying the recursive rule to the first term to yield
$$
f(n,m) = 1 + \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor + \sum_{i=3}^m f(n-i,i) ~,
$$
which may itself be repeated to form a summation over no more than $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n-2}{3}\right\rfloor$ variables, but the computations involved (summations over products of floor functions) become extremely tedious.

Does anyone have suggestions as for how to proceed down this particular attempt at solution, a better method of solution, or a different angle on the problem entirely?

For the curious, this number of descending lists is part of a coefficient in the expansion of the expression $D^n[f^k]$, the n$^\text{th}$ derivative of the k$^\text{th}$ power of some function. Attempting this solely out of curiosity. Thanks ahead of time for reading this mess!

Comment: This is the number $p_k(n)$ of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts. For fixed $k$ it has generating function $\sum p_k(n) t^n = \frac{1}{(1 - t)(1 - t^2)...(1 - t^k)}$ (the proof is by taking the "transpose" of a partition: the transpose of a partition of $n$ into $k$ parts is a partition of $n$ into parts of size at most $k$ and vice versa). Are you familiar with generating functions? In what form would you like an answer? (For fixed $k$ and large $n$ you can write down an explicit closed form using partial fractions.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Aha, you mean [this guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function) -- looks like I didn't take my necessary dose of wikipedia hunting. How do you propose writing the explicit closed form?

Comment: Using partial fractions you can write the generating function as a linear combination of terms of the form $\sum \frac{1}{(1 - \zeta t)^r}$ where $\zeta$ is a root of unity. The coefficients of these terms can be explicitly written down using the binomial theorem with negative exponents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want your lists to be *strictly* decreasing, this is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts; otherwise it’s the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts. The former is given by the triangle [A060016](http://oeis.org/A060016) at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/wiki/Welcome), the second by the triangle [A008284](http://oeis.org/A008284). At those links you’ll find some references, and the latter also has some relevant generating functions.

Comment: Oops, I totally meant the latter (non-strictly). I've calculated a clutch of these numbers as it stands (more than the OEIS list!) but I was mostly curious to see if there's a more tenable and direct closed-form than something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Combinatorial_form) (with the external function $x^k$). The generating functions are an excellent step in the right direction though -- will keep toying with this and reading up.