# Probability that number of successes in Bernoulli trials is divisible by some number

Tags: probability

I have $n$ Bernoulli trials with probabilities of success and failure $p$ and $q=1-p$. How can I find a probability that number of successes is divisible by some given number. I.e. if we choose $3$ than we should consider cases where number of successes equals $0$, $3$, $6$, $9$, etc. Using standard formula for probability of exactly $k$ successes we get

$$
\binom{n}{0}p^0q^{n-0} + \binom{n}{3}p^3q^{n-3} + \binom{n}{6}p^6q^{n-6} + \dots = \sum\limits_k \binom{n}{3k}p^{3k}q^{n-3k}
$$

Is there any way to do this summation and get some analytical expression? For other numbers, I believe, we should just change $k$ multiplier.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918/how-do-i-count-the-subsets-of-a-set-whose-number-of-elements-is-divisible-by-3

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\mathrm i}m\right)$. Then

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n{mk}q^{mk}
&=\frac1m\sum_{j=0}^n\binom njq^j\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}\omega^{jl}\\
&=\frac1m\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom njq^j\omega^{jl}\\
&=\frac1m\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}\left(1+q\omega^l\right)^n\;.
\end{align}

Thus

$$
\sum_k\binom n{mk}p^{mk}q^{n-mk}=\frac1m\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}\left(q+p\exp\left(2\pi\mathrm i\frac lm\right)\right)^n\;.
$$

For $m=3$, this is

$$
\frac13\left(1+2\Re\left(\left(q+p\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\mathrm i}3\right)\right)^n\right)\right)\;.
$$

For $m=4$, it's

$$
\frac14\left(1+(q-p)^n+2\Re\left(\left(q+\mathrm ip\right)^n\right)\right)\;.
$$