# closed form for $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{6}+...+\binom{n}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, summation

closed form for 
$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{6}+...+\binom{n}{n}$$

I tried to solve it by :

$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{6}+...+\binom{n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n/3}\binom{n}{3k}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n/3}\binom{n}{3k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n/3}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\left |z  \right |=1}\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{3k+1}}dz$$

then using geometric series but i got no result .

what is your suggest to solve ?

Comment: are you sure that $n$ *will* be $3k$ for some $k\in \Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Sabyasachi yes for only n=3a ,where is $a \in z$

Comment: Also for what it's worth, this will be equal to $\Re\left((1+\omega)^n\right)$ where $\omega=e^{2i\pi/3}$

Comment: does this count as a closed form?

Comment: Related: [How do I count the subsets of a set whose number of elements is divisible by 3? 4?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/918/)

Comment: You were in the right track. You can sum up to $\displaystyle{\large\infty}$ and the integrand becomes $\displaystyle{\large{\left(1 + z\right)^{\,\,n}z^{2} \over z^{3} - 1}}$ which has three poles. In the integral you must have $\displaystyle{\large\left\vert\, z\,\right\vert > 1}$ instead of $\displaystyle{\large\left\vert\, z\,\right\vert = 1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $3|n$.
$$S_1 = \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{3}+\cdots +\binom{n}{n}\\
S_2 = \binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{4}+\cdots +\binom{n}{n-2}\\
S_3 = \binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{5}+\cdots +\binom{n}{n-1}\\
S_1 + S_2 + S_3 = 2^n\\
S_1 + jS_2 + j^2 S_3 = (1+j)^n = (-1)^{n/3}\\
S_1 + j^2S_2 + j S_3 =   (1+j^2)^n = (-1)^{n/3}
$$
with $j^3 = 1, j\notin \Bbb R$.

Now sum up everything:
$$ 3S_1 + (1+j+j^2)(S_2+S_3) = 2^n + 2(-1)^{n/3}\\
S_1 = \frac 13[2^n + 2(-1)^{n/3}]
$$

Comment: what is $j$?${}$

Comment: this is a complex root of $X^3 = 1$

Comment: ah. see my comment below the question. I came up with something similar. +1

Comment: wait. where do you get $(1+j)^3=-1$?

Comment: $(1+j)^3 = 1 + 3j + 3j^2 + 1 = 1 - 3 +1 = -1$ because the sum of the roots of $X^3-1$ is 0.

Comment: okay nice.${}{}$

Comment: I ended the computation.