# Proof: $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}{n\choose t+rs}=\frac1s\sum\limits_{j=0}^{s-1} \left(2\cos\frac{\pi j}2\right)^n\cos\frac{\pi j(n-2t)}s$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I found somewhere on the internet (I forget where) the strange identity

> For $s,t\in\Bbb Z,\quad 0\leq t<s:$
>   $$\sum_{r\geq0}{n\choose t+rs}=\frac1s\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\left(2\cos\frac{\pi j}2\right)^n\cos\frac{\pi j(n-2t)}s$$ Although I do not know the restrictions on $n$, I suspect $n\in\Bbb N$.

I am attempting to prove this curious identity. I start by defining 
$$F(n;t,s)=\sum_{r\geq0}{n\choose t+rs}$$
I was thinking we could use the integral given by the [Wolfram functions Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/07/01/):
$${n\choose k}=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-ikx}(1+e^{ix})^{n}dx$$
But I am unsure if I would be able validly to interchange the sum and integral signs. Other than that I thought I might be able to use my usual trick of representing the binomial as a beta integral, but I cannot seem to do that in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use binomial theorem for $(1+x)^n$ and apply it for the $s$-th roots of unity. This is a standard method for deriving such identity.

Comment: @i707107 Could you elaborate (in an answer)?

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717185/closed-form-for-binomn0-binomn3-binomn6-binomnn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $s$-th roots of unity $\omega_j=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij}{s}\right), 0\leq j<s$ have the nice property to *filter* elements. For $s>0$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ij n}{s}\right)=
\begin{cases}
1&\qquad s\mid n\\
0& \qquad otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

We can use it for *[series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection)* of $f(z)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_rz^r$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty a_{t+rs}z^{t+rs}=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\omega_j^{-t}f(\omega_jz)\qquad s,t\in\mathbb{Z}, s>0, t\geq 0\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We apply (1) to $f(z)=(1+z)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}z^r$ and obtain setting $z=1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^n}\color{blue}{\binom{n}{t+rs}}&
> =\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\omega_j^{-t}(1+\omega_j)^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\exp\left(-\frac{2i\pi jt}{s}\right)\left(1+\exp\left(\frac{2i\pi j}{s}\right)\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\exp\left(\frac{i\pi j (n-2t)}{s}\right)
> \left(\exp\left(-\frac{i\pi j}{s}\right)+\exp\left(\frac{i\pi j}{s}\right)\right)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi j (n-2t)}{s}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi j(n-2t)}{s}\right)\right)\\
> &\qquad \cdot\left(2\cos\left(\frac{\pi j}{s}\right)\right)^n\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{s}\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\left(2\cos\left(\frac{\pi j}{s}\right)\right)^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi j(n-2t)}{s}\right)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we factor out $\exp\left(\frac{\pi nj}{s}\right)$.
- In (3) we use the identities $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\right)$.
- In (4) we skip the imaginary part (which is zero), since we know the result is real-valued.

Comment: nice exposition Markus (+1), but ..aren't there some extra $i$'s ?

Comment: @GCab: Thanks. :-) Typos corrected. Many thanks for pointing to them.

Comment: Fascinating! Really really great solution! +1

Comment: @clathratus: Many thanks for your nice comment. :-)