# Simplify without using complex numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> Simplify $$\large\sum_{r=0}^{\left \lfloor \frac{n}{3} \right \rfloor}\binom {n}{3r}$$

I tried as much as I could; tried to apply induction, tried to approach combinatorally but failed. I could not resist to see the solution after trying it for all the day. But the answer used complex numbers(cube root of unity and de’moiver’s) and I didn’t find it elegent anyway. In short, I am asking you to simplify it without using complex numbers.

I have asked this on AOPS forum too but people say it cannot be solved without using complex numbers. Please help me!

Comment: It can be simplified using a purely combinatorial proof. See the proof of Theorem 1.1 in [Third and Fourth Binomial Coefficients](https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/49-2/BenjaminScott.pdf), from the [Fibonacci Quarterly, Volume 49, Number 2](https://www.fq.math.ca/49-2.html).

Comment: I find the complex numbers proof really elegant, though. What bothers you about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count the subsets of a set whose number of elements is divisible by 3? 4?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918/how-do-i-count-the-subsets-of-a-set-whose-number-of-elements-is-divisible-by-3)

Comment: Without more context for what kinds of proof you would accept (not liking complex numbers doesn't give Readers much appreciation what you *do* like), I'd have to vote to close for lack of context.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the case $n:=3m$, $m \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$, you can write

$\sum_{r = 0}^m {3m \choose 3r}$

Wolframalpha gives for this:

$\frac{1}{3}\left(2(-1)^{m} + 8^{m}\right)$

[Wolframalpha Calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28%283*m%29%21%2F%28%283*r%29%21%20*%283*m%20-%203*r%29%21%29%29%2C%20r%20%3D%200%20to%20m)

I'm not completly able to reproduce this result, but this is maybe a good starting point.